# How to translate "desires have been granted"

Tags: idioms

I am trying to think of a 4-word 成語 that means "my/your desires have been granted"
but I can't remember or think of one.

Comment: Hmm, are you thinking of “万事如意”？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best fit: 如愿以偿 or 得偿所愿.

Some alternatives might be 心想事成, 万事如意, 梦想成真.

I believe there are still others.

Comment: I have 得偿夙愿 in my dictionary, but not 得偿所愿, is it a typo, or a variation, or something?

Comment: @Ming Both are valid. 夙愿 is something you've wished for a long time. 得偿所愿 is more common.